# open Onvif rtsp recordings

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp

I'm trying to export recordings from a NVT to a file (.mp4) using the Onvif protocol.

Onvif relies in RTSP streams to access live video and recordings.

Saving live video can be done with ffmpeg and it also works great

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i 'rtsp://10.0.0.210:554/cam/liveUrl' -c copy file.mp4
```

But when accessing Onvif recordings I must define the initial absolute dateTime (and final if needed) to be sent to the rtsp server. The info needs to be sent in the PLAY request as the **Range: clock** value.
Another useful setting is the **scale**, that allows to receive the video faster than realtime (useful for downloading)

Sample request using "openRTSP to get the stream

```
PLAY rtsp://10.0.0.1/streamURl/ RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 7
Authorization: Digest ************** 
User-Agent: ./openRTSP (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2023.06.20)
Session: 4001414593142
Scale: 2.000000
Range: clock=20230710T180001Z-20230710T180201Z
```

OpenRTSP supports setting those values as parameter, but it lacks support for h265. So I must use ffmpeg to "fix" the exported files and merge the audio and video streams `ffmpeg -i file_renamed_to.265 -i audio_file -c copy out.mp4`

I would like to bypass openRTSP and use ffmpeg directly. Is it possible to set the "clock range" and the "scale" as ffmpeg args?